# Access class generated by groovy compilation customizer

Tags: groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to have a groovy script with some code, and then I want to copy that code to a method in a generated class. Then just use that class at runtime.

When I run the code below, I get `ClassNotFoundException`. How can I fix it, so that I can create objects of this generated class?

```
class GenerateClassTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String script = ''
        CompilerConfiguration compilerConfiguration = new CompilerConfiguration()
        compilerConfiguration.addCompilationCustomizers(new MyCompilationCustomizer())
        GroovyClassLoader myClassLoader = new GroovyClassLoader()
        GroovyShell groovyShell = new GroovyShell(myClassLoader, new Binding(), compilerConfiguration)
        groovyShell.evaluate(script)
        def newGeneratedClassObj = myClassLoader.loadClass('MyGeneratedClass').newInstance()
    }
}

class MyCompilationCustomizer extends CompilationCustomizer {

    MyCompilationCustomizer() {
        super(CompilePhase.CONVERSION)
    }

    @Override
    void call(SourceUnit source, GeneratorContext context, ClassNode currentClassNode) throws CompilationFailedException {

        ClassNode myNewClass = new AstBuilder().buildFromSpec {
            classNode('MyGeneratedClass', ClassNode.ACC_PUBLIC) {
                classNode Object
                interfaces {}
                mixins {}
            }
        }.first()
        source.getAST().addClass(myNewClass)
    }
}
```

Comment: First, you're not making use of the compiler configuration you are creating, so the customizer will never be called. Next, you need to provide a classloader to the GroovyShell, and get your generated class from there.

Comment: You need to give it a `GroovyClassLoader`, and read from that one.

Comment: I'm using GroovyClassLoader but still the same exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
def newGeneratedClassObj = myClassLoader.loadClass('MyGeneratedClass').newInstance()
```

Use the `GroovyShell` that evaluated the script:

```
def newGeneratedClassObj = groovyShell.getClassLoader().loadClass('MyGeneratedClass').newInstance()
```